# Putting a person that send embed in footer discord.js 14

Tags: discord, discord.js, embed

I'm learning coding and wanted to make a discord bot with tutorial and it went great but now he puts a message.author.tag in footer but

When I try to add `message.author.tag` to the embed footer, I get an error that says that `message is not defined`. This is my code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const embed = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()//deklaracja nowego embeda
    .setTitle('Tytuł embeda')//tytuł
    .setDescription('Embed is great')//opis
    .addFields( // 2 poprzednie linie zapisane za pomocą tego (better)
        {
            name: 'Person1', 
            value: 'Said something', 
            inline: true
        }, // name:(tytuł), value=(opis), inline(czy ma być w linii czy nie, coś jak float)
        {
            name: 'Person2', 
            value: 'Said something', 
            inline: true
        },
        {
            name: 'Person3', 
            value: 'Said something'
        }
)
    .setTimestamp()//pokazuje kiedy zotał wysłany
    .setColor("DarkRed")//color
    .setFooter(message.author.tag)//footer

module.exports = {
    name: 'embed',
    description: 'wysyła embeda',
    usage: '!embed',
    execute: async(message, args) => {
        message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] }) // wysyłanie tego embeda
    }
}
```

And this is the error:

```js
C:\Czymczuk\commands\testCommands\embed.js:12
.setFooter(message.author.tag);//footer
           ^

ReferenceError: message is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Czymczuk\commands\testCommands\embed.js:12:12)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Czymczuk\index.js:20:25)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)

Node.js v18.12.1
```

I tried different commands from the Internet but nothing works. It just says that `(command) is not defined`. I want the embed to show a person in the footer

Comment: Move the `embed` inside the `execute` method. `message` is not available outside of that.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to make embed inside execute comannd
2. In v14 you need to use ({text: }) in embed footer

Try this code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
module.exports = {
    name: 'embed',
    description: 'wysyła embeda',
    usage: '!embed',
    async execute(message, args) {

    const embed = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()//deklaracja nowego embeda
        .setTitle('Tytuł embeda')//tytuł
        .setDescription('Embed is great')//opis
        .addFields(//2 poprzednie linie zapisane za pomocą tego (better)
            {name: 'Person1', value: 'Said something', inline: true},//name:(tytuł), value=(opis), inline(czy ma być w linii czy nie, coś jak float)
            {name: 'Person2', value: 'Said something', inline: true},
            {name: 'Person3', value: 'Said something'}
        )
        .setTimestamp()//pokazuje kiedy zotał wysłany
        .setColor("DarkRed")//color
        .setFooter({text: message.author.tag})//footer
        
        message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})//wysyłanie tego embeda
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response but when i try this code that you send me it says that i can't use const it this place, so i can't make embed in execute beacuse it don't let me i was trying at the beginning to make it in execute but it didn't let me so i make it out of it and it work to time i tried putting a message.author.tag into footer

Comment: @hanori Are yuo shure you are using discord.js v14? It works for me everytime make new question why is this dont work for you

Comment: @hanori I updated the code what i posted. Try it now